# Notification messages in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, notifications, message, vaadin

Do you know a JavaScript library or a GWT module which presents styled notification messages (e.g. info, warning and error messages) as does in Vaadin framework or similar to the Growl component in primefaces?

Answer (score 1):

The [gwt-mosaic](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mosaic/) has something similar. Take a look to the examples in: http://mosaic.analytical-labs.com/#CwInfoPanel

Answer (score 0):

The best library to log messages for GWT (in my opinion) is gwt-log:
- GWT-LOG: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/, Example: http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.demo.LogDemo/LogDemo.html.
- Google-web-toolkit-incubator: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/Logging
- GWT 2.1: Native interface - http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I'm looking for a visual message components not a logger.